# Cloud Functions for Firebase and third party api

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, coinbase-api

My problem is to make use of an API along with Firebase Functions, the API in question is Coinbase, I use the API with node, if I test in the terminal with the node command it works, however when I use it with Firebase Functions Does not work at all, I've been trying to solve the problem for almost a week now.

The code is as follows>

```
    var functions = require('firebase-functions');


    var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
    var client = new Client({
        "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "apiSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    });    


exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {



    this.client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {

        if(accounts){

            response.send(accounts);
         }else{
            response.send(err);

        }

    });
});
```

The error: https://us-central1-investimentos-b7406.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld

The Coinbase API: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/bitcoin-wallet

Comment: Are you using the free [Firebase Spark](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) plan?  It limits outbound networking requests to Google services only.

Comment: Yes I use Spark, so to make a request out of Google need to upgrade?

Comment: Yes, you will need to upgrade.

Answer (score 7):

There's a warning in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start):

> Firebase projects on the Spark plan can make only outbound requests to
>   Google APIs. Requests to third-party APIs fail with an error. For more
>   information about upgrading your project, see [Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

So you'll need to upgrade to a paid plan to use external APIs.